# How to Get System's Date Time Format in C++ Builder 2009

Tags: windows-7, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2009.

I'm looking for a way to get the system's date time format, so that I can use that in displaying dates and times using the system's native format. E.g. If the user's format is English (US) then the display for a day can be "mm/dd/yyyy".

I would prefer a solution that works for both XP and 7. However I'll be happy with an answer that works with just Windows 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `TDateTime`, you can use the `DateTimeToStr()` function which uses the system defaults, unless overridden, to format the string.

Update:  To get the string, use `ShortDateFormat` or `LongDateFormat`

Comment: This works one way. I was hoping to get the formatting, so that I could do more manipulation.

Comment: added the necessary info to get the actual string

Answer (score 0):

ShortDateFormat gives me access to what I need.